# Symfony2 Propel SoftDelete and Dependency injection

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, propel

I used to have soft delete in symfony 1.4 setting except datetime of deletion also the username of the user who soft deleted the object. It was easy then with using sfContect::getInstance() inside the model.

Now this is not possible. So in short what's the best practice to get the username inside model and particular in soft delete behavior?
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/glorpen/GlorpenPropelBundle to [inject services into your model](https://github.com/glorpen/GlorpenPropelBundle#containerawareinterface-for-model) or use [event dispatcher](https://github.com/glorpen/GlorpenPropelBundle#custom-events) to handle this.

Comment: is it possible to give an example?

Comment: Haven't you looked at the links? There are examples.

Comment: Hey, solution with https://github.com/glorpen/GlorpenPropelBundle is the best practice I suppose! Thanks a lot!